# How to go to next record in foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach, explode

In the following code, if `$getd[0]` is empty, I want to go to the next record.

```php
foreach ($arr as $a1) {
  $getd = explode(',' ,$a1);
  $b1 = $getd[0];
}
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

We can use an if statement to only cause something to happen if `$getd[0]` is not empty.

```
foreach ($arr as $a1) {
    $getd=explode(",",$a1);
    if (!empty($getd[0])) {
        $b1=$getd[0];
    }
}
```

Alternatively, we can use the `continue` keyword to skip to the next iteration if `$getd[0]` is empty.

```
foreach ($arr as $a1) {
    $getd=explode(",",$a1);
    if (empty($getd[0])) {
        continue;
    }
    $b1=$getd[0];
}
```

Answer (score 39):

Using [`continue`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) which will skip to the next iteration of the loop.

```
foreach ($arr as $a1){
    $getd=explode(",",$a1);


    if(empty($getd[0])){
        continue;
    }

    $b1=$getd[0];

}
```

Comment: Well maybe you can come back when you get that reputation :) Glad it was what you wanted.